# listfragment action bar menu on click to lunch a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to manage on click events of sub-menus in the action bar overflow. The problem is, my activity is made of several listfragments that should have the same action bar ability.
I have tried doing it the normal way by including an onClick attribute in the menu xml file, but it didn't work, my app crashed.
I have tried doing it through the onOptionsItemSelected function in the main activity, but that, too, doesn't work.I even used the @override annotattion, as instructed by a user here, but, that, too didn't work.
I read on developers.android.com that each listfragment ought to implement the same click event handler in each listfragment, tried that, but it shows an error, and the only way to correct it is to remove the arguments of my intent, since I want to start a new activity on click of an action bar item.
Waiting for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your fragment..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    //inflate the menu here and return true
}
```

and override onOptionsItemSelected(..) to handle menu item clicks..

Comment: does not work. requires me to rename the method getMenuInflater(), after inflating the menu.